# how to protect a route with one of two auth middlewares in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am using multiple auth in my laravel project and it works fine:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admins' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

But I have Problem with protecting some of my routes. I want these routes to be accessed by two type of authentication guards. if '***admins***' guard user is logged in **OR** if '***users***' guard user is logged in, I want to be able to access the route. now my route is like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/add/tutorial',[
        'uses'=>'AddTutorialController@getAddTutorialIndex',
        'as'=>'frontend.add.tutorial'
    ]);
});
```

and with this, just users from my 'users' guard can access this route.

I want to access maybe something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth' OR 'auth:admins']],...
```

**Is there any way to let both of auth guards access the route?? which kind of middleware group I should use?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could add an additional parameter to \app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $default = false)
{
    if($guard && $default) {
        // check for specified $guard OR default guard
        $authorized = Auth::guard($guard)->guest() || Auth::guard(null)->guest();
    } else {
        // use specified guard ( or null if non given )
       $authorized = Auth::guard($guard)->guest();
    }

    if ($authorized) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

With that you can specifiy an additional parameter in a route group :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admins,true'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd('inside');
    }); 
});
```

If you use **auth:admins,true** then the default guard and the specified guard (admins) would be checked with OR.

If you only use **auth** the default guard will be used. If you use **auth:admins** 
the admins guard will be used only.

This is just a quick example. You can adjust it to your needs, or even write an own middleware.

Comment: thanks alot, you saved my time..by a little change on your code I was able to do what I wanted : $authorized = Auth::guard($guard)->guest() && Auth::guard(null)->guest();

Comment: @shock_gone_wild  i have same problem but when run your code i have this error: Auth guard true is not defined. can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean to say `if (!$authorized)` instead of `if ($authorized)`?

Answer (score 0):

i found 3 ways, if you can found useful:-

First Way:-

```
routes.php

Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth', 'auth:admins']], function () {
    Route::get('/add/tutorial',[
        'uses'=>'AddTutorialController@getAddTutorialIndex',
        'as'=>'frontend.add.tutorial'
    ]);
});
```

Second Way:-

```
routes.php

Route::get('/add/tutorial',[
   'uses'=>'AddTutorialController@getAddTutorialIndex',
   'as'=>'frontend.add.tutorial'
])->middleware(['auth', 'auth:admins']);
```

Third Way:-

```
routes.php

Route::get('/add/tutorial',[
   'uses'=>'AddTutorialController@getAddTutorialIndex',
   'as'=>'frontend.add.tutorial'
])


yourcontroller.php

class YourController extends Controller{ 
    public function __construct(){
       $this->middleware(['auth', 'auth:admins']);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I had tried this way but your suggestion middleware group needs both authentication together. I want check if one of them is logged in, is enough and access the route. how can I put OR somewhere in the group?

Comment: ok use if else condition in controller like 
if(\Auth::user()->type == "admin"){
 $this->middleware('auth:admins');
}else{
$this->middleware('auth');
}

Comment: I think it is going to work as I want, you are the best.. just one question, there is no way to use middleware group in the routes.php file to do what I want? the just way is that I must use this condition in the controller?

Comment: Why don't you write your own middleware for this cases?

Comment: I tried creating a custom middleware but I couldn't write the condition for returning $request , would you please give me the code?

Comment: Yes we can, but i am out now

Comment: Use same condition in routes.php